# onActivityResult is not calling between activites

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-api-levels

Here I have tried to pass the some value to 2nd activity(Child) to 1st activity(Parent). I have noted that in API-21 above version of device onActivityResult is called but for API-19 and below of it, it is not called. Here I share snippets of my code.Please check it.

Your answer is more appreciated!!!

**In parent activity:**

**STEP 1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ABCAct.this, DEF.class);
                intent.putExtra("mapPickDrop", "1");
                intent.putExtra("location_lat", P_latitude);
                intent.putExtra("location_lng", P_longitude);
                intent.putExtra("address", pickupAddressFlag);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2018);
```

**STEP 2:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == 2018) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Double lat = data.getDoubleExtra("location_lat", 0.0);
                Double lng = data.getDoubleExtra("location_lng", 0.0);
                String add = data.getStringExtra("location_address");
                String mapPickDrop = data.getStringExtra("mapPickDrop");

                if (mapPickDrop.equals("1")) {
                    P_latitude = lat;
                    P_longitude = lng;
                    pickupAddressFlag = add;
                    TaxiUtil.bookTaxiPickUpDrop = 1;
                    if (P_latitude != 0.0 && P_longitude != 0.0 && D_latitude == 0.0 && D_longitude == 0.0) {
                        setLocation(P_latitude, P_longitude, "");
                    }
                }
                if (mapPickDrop.equals("2")) {
                    TaxiUtil.bookTaxiPickUpDrop = 2;
                    D_latitude = lat;
                    D_longitude = lng;
                    DroplocEdt.setText("" + add); 
                    showPickupDropMarkers();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**In Child activity**

```
   Intent back = new Intent();
            back.putExtra("location_lat", P_latitude_new);
            back.putExtra("location_lng", P_longitude_new);
            back.putExtra("location_address",         PicklocEdt_1.getText().toString());

            back.putExtra("mapPickDrop", mapPickDrop);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, back);
            finish();
```

**Manifest**

```
<activity
            android:name=".ABCAct"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateAlwaysHidden">

     <activity
            android:name=".DEF"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Comment: Please check the Manifest code @MuratK.

Comment: remove the android:launchMode="singleTask".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:Deleting `android:noHistory="true"` from the activity I was having problem with solved the issue for me

2: Change if you have `android:launchMode=“singleTask”` to `android:launchMode=“standard”`

hope it helps!!!!

Comment: By changing  android:launchMode=“singleTask” to android:launchMode=“standard”. It is worked. Thank you @Adnan Maqbool